# Chrony reporting system time slower than NTP and growing

Tags: amazon-ec2, ntp, clock-synchronization, chrony

I have chrony running on several of my instances. Unfortuantely, on one of them, it keeps reporting that the system time is slower than NTP time. This number of seconds keeps growing at a rate of about 10 seconds per minute. Here is one reading:

```
Reference ID : D8E50445 (triton.ellipse.net)
Stratum : 3
Ref time (UTC) : Mon Dec 18 21:09:33 2017
System time : 10.736123085 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset : +0.000084658 seconds
RMS offset : 0.001023541 seconds
Frequency : 217553.062 ppm slow
Residual freq : +0.017 ppm
Skew : 0.698 ppm
Root delay : 0.050225362 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.009489730 seconds
Update interval : 71.6 seconds
Leap status : Normal
```

and a few minuts later:

```
Reference ID : D8E50445 (triton.ellipse.net)
Stratum : 3
Ref time (UTC) : Mon Dec 18 21:17:55 2017
System time : 49.262691498 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset : +0.000187908 seconds
RMS offset : 0.000752060 seconds
Frequency : 217553.109 ppm slow
Residual freq : +0.007 ppm
Skew : 0.306 ppm
Root delay : 0.050148461 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.016217658 seconds
Update interval : 71.3 seconds
Leap status : Normal
```

Here is my config file:

```
# use the local instance NTP service, if available
#server 169.254.169.123 prefer iburst
server 0.amazon.pool.ntp.org  prefer iburst
server 1.amazon.pool.ntp.org  prefer iburst
server 2.amazon.pool.ntp.org  prefer iburst
server 3.amazon.pool.ntp.org  prefer iburst

# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
pool 2.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Record the rate at which the system clock gains/losses time.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift

# Allow the system clock to be stepped in the first three updates
# if its offset is larger than 1 second.
#makestep 1.0 3
makestep 1000 10

# Enable hardware timestamping on all interfaces that support it.
#hwtimestamp *

# Increase the minimum number of selectable sources required to adjust
# the system clock.
minsources 2

# Allow NTP client access from local network.
#allow 192.168.0.0/16

# Serve time even if not synchronized to a time source.
#local stratum 10

# Specify file containing keys for NTP authentication.
#keyfile /etc/chrony.keys

## Get TAI-UTC offset and leap seconds from the system tz database.
#leapsectz right/UTC

# Specify directory for log files.
logdir /var/log/chrony

# Select which information is logged.
log measurements statistics tracking

# save data between restarts for fast re-load
dumponexit
dumpdir /var/run/chrony
```

I have no idea what to look into further. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a VM or physical host? also if it supports it can you postthe output from `ntpq -pcrv` or equivalent.

Comment: It is an m1-small (VM). The issue went away after a few days. Now it seems to be ok. I can only guess it was the VM issue. Thanks!